# Track content change in Audit Trail

Tags: sharepoint-online, auditing

My site in Office 365 environment. I would like to track list item content change Ex: In one of the list my title field value is "Sample 1" and I have changed it to "Sample 2". Now I want to see both values (original and new) in audit trail report.

Is is possible to track through default audit trail functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have that through versioning, if you enable versioning on the list, then edit an item, you will see all the changes made appearing there.

Comment: After enabling versioning of list content is not coming in audit trail report. I have created "Content modifications" report.

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution You don't see it in the audit settings.  You see it under version history for the item.

Comment: It not solve my purpose because admin wants to see the all the activities performed on list in audit trail report.